# Excel VBA Check if the pivotitem is valid with a if statment

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

The below VBA code which change the pivotfiels of a pivottable is working, but i would like to add a further step to check if the string entered in the inputbox is one of the correct pivotItems.

Working code:

```
Sub ChooseMonth()

Dim MyMONTH As Variant
Dim MySTRING  As String

MyMONTH = Application.InputBox("Enter the MONTH in a full text format")
 MySTRING = MyMONTH

Sheets("All results excl not tested").Select

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MySTRING
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MySTRING
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MySTRING
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MySTRING
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MySTRING
End Sub
```

So I tried differents options to check if the string entered is one of the pivotitems but no one is working yet.

Any ideas.

```
Dim MyMONTH As Variant
Dim MySTRING  As String
Set pi = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Test Month").PivotItems


 MyMONTH = Application.InputBox("Enter the MONTH in a full text format")
 MySTRING = MyMONTH

 Sheets("All results excl not tested").Select

    If MySTRING = pi Then
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MySTRING
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MySTRING
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MySTRING
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MySTRING
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MySTRING
     Else
         MsgBox "There is a typo, please enter again the Month"
         MyMONTH = Application.InputBox("Enter the MONTH in a full text format")
     End If

 End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: Why is there a random `End Sub` right above the comment _GoTo MyMONTH_? Also I may have misinterpreted this, but isn't 
1. MyString = MyMonth
2. If pi = MyMonth => pi = MyString
3. Hence, pi <> MyString will **never** occur.
So, you're generating dead code on that line. 
You could set a bool in the for each if you find a matching item. If bool is still false -> Typo

Comment: Thanks EngJon, i am reviewing my code and intergerting a boolean in it.

Comment: EngJon, when i defined "MyString" as a boolean, the working part of the code wasn't working anymore.

Comment: Your sentence holds ambigous statements. 1: You have declared a new Boolean called "MyString" or 2. you have just changed "MySTRING" to `Dim MySTRING As Boolean`. Either way, this won't work. 1: VBA is canse insensitive, so you have duplicate names 2: It's not enough to just redeclare an existing string to bool. You have to use it the right way. 1. Declare the bool, set it to false, 2. Iterate through pivottables. If you find the entered name -> set bool to true 3. After iteration, a false bool indicates an invalid input ->MsgBox

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I did option 2. So I will implement your  suggestion and let you know the results. Thanks again for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

For each pivot table you need to iterate through the values, something like this

```
dim APivotItem  as PivotItem 
dim pt as pivottable

for each pt in   ActiveSheet.PivotTables
for each APivotItem in pt.PageFields("Test Month").PivotItems

   if APivotItem.name =  MyMONTH then
   ' found in this pivot table
   end if

next
next
```